# LINQ- inserting into conjoining tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I've got a conjunction table, which is a one to many relationship. My LINQ code will not insert into this table because it has no primary key, even though the table is composed of just foreign keys. In addition, when I try to save the relationship for one of my foreign keys, it says that the ALTER_TABLE statement conflicts with the FOREIGN_KEY constraint. But I've checked all through both of the tables in question and there is no ALTER_TABLE anywhere.

How can I make changes that will allow me to insert into my conjunction table?

Comment: Can you please post some code for the Linq part of the problem? As for the alter_table statement, I think you are trying to change the table and when you save it whatever ide you are using is telling you that it can't alter the table because it would violate a foreign key constraint. You might have data in the conjunction table that is now invalid because of the change. If you know the structure is correct, clear the data from the conjunction table then save the changes to the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a primary key on the table, that is a composite key of the foreign key columns.  LINQ-to-SQL should like that a lot better.  It will allow you to keep your current structure but provide a key that LINQ-to-SQL can use.